# How to Dynamically change a logback variable (filename)?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am currently working on a spring-boot batch application who detect new files and read them. All is working well, but i have a problem with the filename of the logs.
The thing is, the filename of each log (one for each file) must be created dynamically while the batch is running, and i don't know how to change dynamically the log's filename in the logback.

This is my logback for the moment (${TECH} is what i want to change) :

```
<configuration debug="false" scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <springProperty scope="context" name="directory.log.tech" source="bpa.batch.directory.log.technique"/>
    <appender name="TECHNIQUE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.LevelFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
            <onMatch>DENY</onMatch>
            <onMismatch>ACCEPT</onMismatch>
        </filter>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${directory.log.tech}\%d{yyyyMMdd}.${TECH}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="fr.hm.bpa.log.LogTechnique" level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="TECHNIQUE" />
    </logger>
</configuration>
```

Could someone explain how to change it while my code is running ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same question

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [Sifting File Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#SiftingAppender) that's built into logback.

From the documentation:

> As its name implies, a SiftingAppender can be used to separate (or
>   sift) logging according to a given runtime attribute. For example,
>   SiftingAppender can separate logging events according to user
>   sessions, so that the logs generated by different users go into
>   distinct log files, one log file per user.